# Send mail using old domain

Tags: dns, sendmail

I have just sent a test email through PHP from my server using mail-tester.com.

The Received: section states the following:

`Received: from OLD_domain_name (ptr_record_for_ip [my.ip.address])`

Old was the previous PTR record and also an entry listed in the `/etc/hosts` file against that specific IP address.

I've since checked on mxtoolbox and the PTR record is definitely updated (and is reflected in that Recieved: section anyway) so what I'm confused about is how the OLD domain name is still being used.

And before you ask - I have checked `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` and there are no sendmail parameters there either. So I'm wondering where to look to change this OLD_domain name?

I haven't restarted the server but would ideally not want to.

Comment: php and apache or php only ? If php as apache module, take a look at your apache config for hostname

Comment: Its php & apache - so where would I find that setting?

Comment: `grep -RniI  --include='*.conf' host /etc/apache2/*`